# UIScrollBar with wider/bigger buttons

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, uiscrollview, scrollbar

I made a touch screen application and I used a `UIScrollBar` for one of my TextField in there and I want to make it's buttons wider/bigger. The `.width` and `.scaleX` and also `.setSize()` properties are not working. I change size of all components inside the `UIScrollBar` (make wider), but it keeps its original width size with no changes.  Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

G Skinner is the man. He added scrollbar width inside the scrollbar component class, you can download his source and see instructions here:
http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2007/05/variable_scroll.html
Use it along with you custom skinning.